# I need to show information without brackets

Tags: arrays, swift, string

[image]

I have code that get weather api but information from "weather" prints "id" and "main" information in console and also in text label with brackets in console

```
(
    250
)
```

Here is some relevant code:

```
 if let weather = jsonObj.value(forKey: "weather") as? NSArray {

     let idObject = weather.value(forKey: "id")
     // DispatchQueue.main.sync {
     // self.weatherLabel.text = idObject as? String }
     print (idObject)

     let mainObject = weather.value(forKey: "main")
     print(mainObject as Any)
 }
```

Comment: add the console print line so we can understand your problem

Comment: First you cast the value from jsonObj as an NSArray, you should use the native swift Array btw, and then you do value(forKey:) on that array. That can’t work

Comment: can you add your json object so question would be easy to understand.

Comment: Or if you’re using a third-party web service, share information about which web service you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Below, in the second half of this answer, I’ll describe what the issue is in your code snippet. But you are using Swift, so you shouldn’t be using `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` at all. You should use `JSONDecoder` to parse your json, and deal solely with Swift objects.

So you might define structures like so:

```
struct WeatherReport: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let main: String
}

struct ResponseObject : Decodable {
    let weather: [WeatherReport]
}
```

And decode it like so:

```
do {
    let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseObject.self, from: data)
    for weatherReport in responseObject.weather {
        print(weatherReport.id)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Now, my definition of `WeatherReport` is undoubtedly incorrect, as it needs to match your JSON structure, which you haven’t shared with us. For example, I’m assuming your `id` values are numeric (no quotes around them; we can’t tell by looking at your output). Also, you should check the documentation and figure out what the JSON looks like if there was an error. So you’d have to check that. But hopefully this illustrates the idea.

---

Regarding why you’re seeing the `(` and `)` around your values, that’s because the objects you are printing are, themselves, `NSArray` objects. When you call `value(forKey:)` on a `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` objects, it will go through the array and grab the value associated with that key for each dictionary in your array, and will return an array of values. Hence the `(` and `)` in the output. Sure, your “array of dictionaries” appears to currently have only one dictionary in it, but the fact that it is an array suggests that it’s possible that `weather` can possibly contain multiple dictionaries.

Consider this over-simplified version of your JSON:

```
{
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 42,
            "main": "Rain"
        },
        {
            "id": 520
            "main": "Cloudy"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thus

```
if let weather = jsonObj.value(forKey: "weather") as? NSArray {
    let identifiers = weather.value(forKey: "id")
    print (identifiers)
}
```

Will output

```
(
    42,
    520
)
```

Now, your array of dictionaries obviously only has one dictionary at this point, but this illustrates what’s going on.

If you don’t want the brackets, get the `firstObject` from the array:

```
guard
    let weather = jsonObj.value(forKey: "weather") as? NSArray,
    let weatherReport = weather.firstObject as? NSDictionary
else {
    return
}

if let idObject = weatherReport.value(forKey: "id") as? Int {
    print(idObject)
}
```

Or, if you want to print all of them:

```
guard
    let weather = jsonObj.value(forKey: "weather") as? NSArray
else {
    return
}

for object in array {
    if let weatherReport = weather as? NSDictionary, let identifier = weatherReport["id"] as? Int {
        print(identifier)
    }
}
```

This is how one navigates a `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` objects. But, as described at the beginning of my answer, you shouldn’t be using these `NS` types at all. Get your raw `Data`, and decode it to model object types using `JSONDecoder`, instead.